# Rendering issue in Chrome with CSS border style

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So I have this table:

[image: Rendered upgrade table]

I have some JavaScript code that highlights the current plan the user is on, this then changes if they upgrade or downgrade.

When the upgrade button is clicked and the page renders it produces unwanted side effects as shown below:

[image: Upgrade table]

It's almost as if it applies an extra `border-top` to every other `<td>` tag. Now when I refresh the page it works okay. To add to the confusion also when I don't add a `border-right` and `border-left` attribute it works fine when the 'Upgrade' or 'Downgrade' buttons are pressed.

[image: Upgrade table without border right and left]

I've tested it in Firefox and Safari also, Firefox renders it okay but it's still producing unwanted side effects in Safari.

Does anyone know why this is?

```
$('#' + params['current_plan']).addClass('current_pricing_plan');`
$(".current_pricing_plan button").prop("disabled", true);`

.current_pricing_plan {
border-bottom: 2px solid #00a6cd!important;
border-left: 2px solid #00a6cd;
border-right: 2px solid #00a6cd;
border-top: 2px solid #00a6cd!important;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

The first block of code is the JS and the second is the CSS, i'm using Rails so heres an example of one of the `<tr>`'s in the html.erb file.

```
<tr id="750" class="current-pricing-plan">
  <td><strong>£25</strong><span class="smalltxt"> /month</span></td>
  <td><strong>750</strong><span class="smalltxt"> mins&nbsp;included</span></td>
  <td><strong>4p</strong><span class="smalltxt"> /min&nbsp;thereafter</span></td>
  <td class="last-col">
    <button class="btn smallbtn confirm_opener_750-25">
    <span class="hidetextmobile"></span>
    <% if @account.billing_plan.inclusive_minutes > 750 %>
      <span class="your-plan">Downgrade</span><span class="your-plan-none">Your Plan</span>
    <% else %>
       <span class="your-plan">Upgrade</span><span class="your-plan-none">Your Plan</span>
    <% end %>
  </button>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Adding your markup and the js for this functionality helps.

Comment: `StackOverflow != Flicker`; please prepare a Fiddle ([better](http://jsfiddle.net/)), or post relevant only CSS and HTML (minimum)

Comment: Please note that if you paste markup directly in the window, it won't appear. Please indent it four spaces to ensure it is formatted properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better replace your `border` with [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) attribute.

```
.current_pricing_plan {
outline: 2px solid #00a6cd!important;
}
```

Comment: @ArranScott I'm glad I was able to help.